# Does exist any way to do a responsive menu with sass/compass?

Tags: javascript, susy-compass, compass-sass

i'm new on compass and i'm discovering compass and susy.
actually i got a menu as list and i would to convert it to a select dropdown when it meet the breakpoint for mobile.

Does exist any way to do a responsive menu with these tools ? or do i add another tool ?
for another tools, does it be a compass plugin or a js library like [selectnav](http://lukaszfiszer.github.com/selectnav.js/) ?

thanks

Comment: Just write the 'responsive' code into the SASS using media queries and compile it . . .

Comment: i know that but i need to know if this code is provided by compass or i f i need to use another tool like a js librarie...

Comment: Compass and Susy can both be helpful in building a dropdown menu at a breakpoint, but neither one has all the code pre-written for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using SASS/Compass features (here is tutorials and examples: http://thesassway.com/guides) you can simplify process of writing CSS styles. But if you want to get dropdown menu "from the box", you will not find it there. You have to create it yourself. If you don't want to do it, you can use, for example, Twitter Bottstrap (http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/) which have customiziable dropdown menus for you and a lot of other helpful elements.

Comment: so, can i pick element from zurb or other compass plugin to do this, with keeping susy as bas grid system ?

Comment: for example, which part of foundation do i need to pick ?